# Factory Initializer + Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton, factory

I wrote a non-static Generic class instantiator for my Abstract Factory design, and use Singleton approach to make sure that only 1 instance of the instantiator will be initialized for every client request.

```
public sealed class FactoryInstantiator<T> where T: class
{
    private static readonly FactoryInstantiator<T> _instance = new Instantiator<T>();
    public static FactoryInstantiator<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            _client = HttpContext.Current.Session["ClientCode"].ToString();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private static string _client;
    private string _className;
    private string _fullyQualifiedClassName;
    private string _assemblyName;

    private FactoryInstantiator() { }

    public T CreateInstance()
    {
        string fullClassName = typeof(T).ToString();
        string[] splitClassName = fullClassName.Split('.');
        _className = splitClassName[2];
        _assemblyName = splitClassName[0] + "." + _client + "." + splitClassName[1];
        _fullyQualifiedClassName = _assemblyName + "." + _className;

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_fullyQualifiedClassName + "," + _assemblyName));
    }
}
```

I abstracted the the whole namespace for each Client

```
namespace InventorySuite.Factory.BusinessLogic
{
    // abstract factory
    public abstract class InvoiceFactory
    {
        public abstract void Set() { }
    }
}

namespace InventorySuite.Client1.BusinessLogic
{
    // concrete invoice class for Client1
    public class Invoice : InvoiceFactory
    {
        public override void Set() { }
    }
}

namespace InventorySuite.Client2.BusinessLogic
{
    // concrete invoice class for Client2
    public class Invoice : InvoiceFactory
    {
        public override void Set() { }
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    InvoiceFactory clientInvoice;

    Session.Add("ClientCode", "Client1");
    clientInvoice = FactoryInstantiator<InvoiceFactory>.Instance.CreateInstance();
    clientInvoice.Set();

    Session["ClientCode"] = "Client2";
    clientInvoice = FactoryInstantiator<InvoiceFactory>.Instance.CreateInstance();
    clientInvoice.Set();

}
```

It works well and already tested it, but my question is about its efficiency/performance hit, since I use reflection here, and for the Singleton approach if it has multi-threading issues (afaik, the singleton instance will be shared in all clients). I will also appreciate any other approach on this. thanks

Comment: Seems like a solution looking for a problem, to me.

Comment: Put a lock around the line which creates the factory, and test the performance by calling the factory thousands of times in a loop, measuring & comparing the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any multi-threading issue since you're creating a new instance every time.

About the performance. You can measure the time creating 100 instances:

```
long ini = Environment.TickCount;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Session["ClientCode"] = "Client2";
    clientInvoice = FactoryInstantiator<InvoiceFactory>.Instance.CreateInstance();
    clientInvoice.Set();
}
long timeCreate100Instances = Environment.TickCount - ini;
```

Using `reflection`, the performance hit resides in loading the assembly. I think that in your case, the class you're loading is in the same dll, you you also will not experiment any performance issue.

In other case, you can cache the `Assembly` obejcts in a `Hastable/Dictionary` in your `CreateInstance()` method.

Answer (score 0):

using Richard and Daniel suggestions, I was able to reduce the performance hit of reflection using Caching. I therefore conclude that Reflection really has huge performance issues.

```
  public T CreateInstance()
    {
        string fullClassName = typeof(T).ToString();
        string[] splitClassName = fullClassName.Split('.');
        _className = splitClassName[2];
        _assemblyName = splitClassName[0] + "." + _client + "." + splitClassName[1];
        _fullyQualifiedClassName = _assemblyName + "." + _className;

        // use caching
        T obj;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[_fullyQualifiedClassName] == null)
        {
            obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_fullyQualifiedClassName + "," + _assemblyName));
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(_fullyQualifiedClassName, obj, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
        else
        {
            obj = (T)HttpContext.Current.Cache[_fullyQualifiedClassName];
        }

        return obj;
    }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvoiceFactory inv;

    Stopwatch globalTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    //normal instantiation
    globalTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10000; x++)
        inv = new InventorySuit.Client1.BusinessLogic.Invoice;
    globalTimer.Stop();
    Response.Write(globalTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "<BR>");
    //result 0ms


    // using singleton factory w/o caching
    globalTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10000; x++)
        inv = new FactoryInstantiator<InvoiceFactory>().CreateInstance();
    globalTimer.Stop();
    Response.Write(globalTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "<BR>");
    //result 129ms

    // using singleton factory w/ caching
    for (int x = 0; x <= 10000; x++)
        inv = FactoryInstantiator<InvoiceFactory>.Instance.CreateInstance();
    globalTimer.Stop();
    Response.Write(globalTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "<BR>");
    //result 21ms



}
```

Comment: I added 1 digit on that for loop ctr and the result was telling.

Comment: Be carefull, because now you're using a shared instance, now you could have multi-threading issues. Your instances now must be thread safe.

Comment: you conclude that reflection has huge performance issues from this? I would conclude that, although plain reflection is ~6 times slower than your chached version, if you can instantiate 10000 items in 129ms, that's fast enough for anyone.

Comment: @Daniel you mean the Cache instance? how about I store it on Session State instead? does this solve multi threading issue since different users have different sessions? thanks

Comment: @Matt, i replace 10000 to 1000000, and the reflected instance without cache is 2sec slower and the non-cached is 12sec slower. In my project, I might use the instantiator inside a loop that displays thousands or even millions of data from the database =)

Answer (score 0):

Loading the assemblies in Session State to solve multi-threading issue.

```
   public T CreateInstance()
    {
        string fullClassName = typeof(T).ToString();
        string[] splitClassName = fullClassName.Split('.');
        _className = splitClassName[2];
        _assemblyName = splitClassName[0] + "." + _client + "." + splitClassName[1];
        _fullyQualifiedClassName = _assemblyName + "." + _className;


        T obj;
        var assemblies = HttpContext.Current.Session["ASSEMBLIES"] as Dictionary<string, T>;

        if (assemblies == null)
        {
            assemblies = new Dictionary<string, T>();
            assemblies.Add(_fullyQualifiedClassName, null);
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("ASSEMBLIES", assemblies);
        }

        obj = assemblies[_fullyQualifiedClassName] as T;

        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_fullyQualifiedClassName + "," + _assemblyName));
            assemblies[_fullyQualifiedClassName] = obj;
        }



        return obj;
    }
```